# Multiple typelists for parameterized tests

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm currently working on unit testing a conversion class I wrote using Google Test. I would like to test for all kinds of floating point types, so I found typed tests. But my conversion class offers a bunch of types itself (millimeter, centimeter, decimeter, meter, kilometer as an example - but my conversions are a little trickier). So now I want to test all possible combinations of my measures of length for all floating point types. And as a plus I have specified input and output min/max values for my conversion results, which differ from conversion to conversion (the input/output values of meter to centimeter are different to those of centimeter to kilometer for instance).

Also I know about parameterized tests, but Google Tests to be only allowing to hand in one list of test types after another.

What I could to is write a templated struct like this:

```
template<class From, class To, class Value>
struct triple
{
  typedef From source;
  typedef To target;
  typedef Value value_t;
}
```

And create a testing::Types<...> list with all possible combinations. But that's cumbersome, ugly and I still don't have my input/output bounding values covered.

Would there be a way to let Google Test use two lists, one with the floating point types (`float`, `double`, `long` double) and one list containing only the combinations of my measures of length types?

Comment: Not fully understand your requirement, but you may use `struct integral_constant` to pass values as type.

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Thank you!

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to bundle two types into a little composite template class for Gtest. it sounds like the core of your question is,  how to obtain the Cartesian product of two lists of types? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122028/how-to-create-the-cartesian-product-of-a-type-list