# How can I create a n way Cartesian product of type lists in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates

Self explanatory.

Basically, say I have type lists like so:

```
using type_list_1 = type_list<int, somestructA>;
using type_list_2 = type_list<somestructB>;
using type_list_3 = type_list<double, short>;
```

They can be variadic number of type lists.

How do I get a typelist of Cartesian product?

```
result = type_list<
type_list<int, somestructB, double>,
type_list<int, somestructB, short>,
type_list<somestructA, somestructB, double>,
type_list<somestructA, somestructB, short>
>;
```

I did dabble on how to create a two-way Cartesian product as given here: *[How to create the Cartesian product of a type list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122028/how-to-create-the-cartesian-product-of-a-type-list)*, but n way seems to be no so trivial.

For now I am trying...

```cpp
template <typename...> struct type_list{};

// To concatenate
template <typename... Ts, typename... Us>
constexpr auto operator|(type_list<Ts...>, type_list<Us...>) {
   return type_list{Ts{}..., Us{}...};
}

template <typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
constexpr auto cross_product_two(type_list<T, Ts...>, type_list<Us...>) {
    return (type_list<type_list<T,Us>...>{} | ... | type_list<type_list<Ts, Us>...>{});
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
constexpr auto cross_product_impl() {
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Ts) >0) {
        return cross_product_impl<decltype(cross_product_two(T{}, U{})), Ts...>();
    } else {
        return cross_product_two(T{}, U{});
    }
}
```

**I will just say that considering how difficult it is to get it right, just use boost as in the answer by Barry.** Unfortunately I have to be stuck with a hand rolled approach because to use boost or not is a decision that comes from somewhere else :(

Comment: Oof, you're a glutton for punishment 

Comment: I kinda suck at it, but can you modify 2-way cartesian product in a way that: 1) first typelist is actually a typelist of typelists of 1 type; 2) instead of concatenating two types from typelists, the metafunction would append types from second list to "child" lists of first typelist (in a cartesian-product-way)? If it is feasible, the problem can be easily solved with recursive algorithm.

Comment: The real difficulty in a recursive implementation is that `cartesian_product` is a list of type lists, and at each recursion step you want to append stuff to each inner type list. Getting into that second packing level of pack takes some deduction...

Comment: I guess you could also implement it "linearly" by looking at this as an N-dimensional "type space" where you want to traverse each "type grid point". You compute the number of grid points, then you just traverse it like you would through a flattened ND array and compute the types at each grid point. Something to consider...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Something along the lines of "*[A cartesian product of tuples in C++17](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/217452/a-cartesian-product-of-tuples-in-c17)*"?

Comment: @Deduplicator Yep, exactly!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_productf_l), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```
using result = mp_product<
    type_list,
    type_list_1, type_list_2, type_list_3>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7qXeen).

Comment: Holy cow... But I feel obliged to point out that (sampling each code several times on godbolt) the Mp11 version takes about twice as long to compile. Not sure how much of that overhead is parsing the boost header itself and how much is instantiating templates...

Comment: @MaxLanghof Sure. 1.5x if you only include `algorithm.hpp` instead of all of Mp11. And even then we're talking 0.08s vs 0.12s. Have to factor in how long it took me to write this too.

Comment: @Barry: From a software engineering standpoint, with you 100%. There's also how easy this is to read vs a hand-rolled approach. Also there is little to no testing required to ensure the correctness of the library solution. Overall less code and higher confidence will lead to lower maintenance costs for its lifetime.

Comment: I agree this is quite simple but unfortunately there exists teams that frown on boost.

Comment: there are teams that frown on everything. this is not a reason to not use it.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava Sometimes those decisions are not for us to make and we need to live with it.

Answer (score 13):

Ok, got it. It's not pretty but it works:

```
template<class ... T>
struct type_list{};

struct somestructA{};
struct somestructB{};

using type_list_1 = type_list<int, somestructA, char>;
using type_list_2 = type_list<somestructB>;
using type_list_3 = type_list<double, short, float>;

template<class TL1, class TL2>
struct add;

template<class ... T1s, class ... T2s>
struct add<type_list<T1s...>, type_list<T2s...>>
{
    using type = type_list<T1s..., T2s...>;
};

template<class ... TL>
struct concat;

template<class TL, class ... TLs>
struct concat<TL, TLs...>
{
    using type = typename add<TL, typename concat<TLs...>::type>::type;
};

template<class TL>
struct concat<TL>
{
    using type = TL;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<type_list<int, somestructA, char, double, short, float>, typename add<type_list_1, type_list_3>::type>);

template<class TL1, class TL2>
struct multiply_one;

// Prepends each element of T1 to the list T2.
template<class ... T1s, class ... T2s>
struct multiply_one<type_list<T1s...>, type_list<T2s...>>
{
    using type = typename concat<type_list<type_list<T1s, T2s...>...>>::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    type_list<
        type_list<int, double, short, float>,
        type_list<somestructA, double, short, float>,
        type_list<char, double, short, float>
        >,
    typename multiply_one<type_list_1, type_list_3>::type>);

// Prepends each element of TL to all type lists in TLL.
template<class TL, class TLL>
struct multiply_all;

template<class TL, class ... TLs>
struct multiply_all<TL, type_list<TLs...>>
{
    using type = typename concat<typename multiply_one<TL, TLs>::type...>::type;
};

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    type_list<
        type_list<int, double, short, float>,
        type_list<somestructA, double, short, float>,
        type_list<char, double, short, float>
        >,
    typename multiply_all<type_list_1, type_list<type_list_3>>::type>);

static_assert(std::is_same_v<
    type_list<
        type_list<int, somestructB>,
        type_list<somestructA, somestructB>,
        type_list<char, somestructB>,
        type_list<int, double, short, float>,
        type_list<somestructA, double, short, float>,
        type_list<char, double, short, float>
        >,
    typename multiply_all<type_list_1, type_list<type_list_2, type_list_3>>::type>);

template<class TL, class ... TLs>
struct cartesian_product
{
    using type = typename multiply_all<TL, typename cartesian_product<TLs...>::type>::type;
};

template<class ... Ts>
struct cartesian_product<type_list<Ts...>>
{
    using type = type_list<type_list<Ts>...>;
};


using expected_result = type_list<
    type_list<int, somestructB, double>,
    type_list<somestructA, somestructB, double>,
    type_list<char, somestructB, double>,
    type_list<int, somestructB, short>,
    type_list<somestructA, somestructB, short>,
    type_list<char, somestructB, short>,
    type_list<int, somestructB, float>,
    type_list<somestructA, somestructB, float>,
    type_list<char, somestructB, float>
>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<expected_result,
    cartesian_product<type_list_1, type_list_2, type_list_3>::type>);
```

https://godbolt.org/z/L5eamT

I left my own `static_assert` tests in there for... Well, I hope they help.

Also, I'm sure there has to be a nicer solution. But this was the obvious "I know this will eventually lead to the goal" path. I eventually had to resort to adding a `concat` or sorts, I'm sure that it could be used much earlier to skip most of the cruft.

Comment: Template programming that I can follow.  That's awesome.  I learned something today.

Comment: add takes two type_lists. How are you passing multiple type lists to add in concat?

Comment: @themagicalyang Well-spotted, that's a bug (which the tests didn't find cos all involved lists were only length 2). The `...` has to go inside the recursive `concat` call, not outside. Answer (including test cases) corrected. Proves Barry right regarding correctness expectations :)

Comment: Isn't the cartesian product call to multiply_all bascially a multiple_one?

Comment: @themagicalyang No. `cartesian_product` implements the recursion. `multiply_all` does a `multiply_one` for each type list in the `TLs` pack. `cartesian_product::type` is a list of type lists. `multiply_all` takes a type list and a list of type lists. `multiply_one` takes two type lists `a1, a2, a3` and `b1, b2, b3` and creates `a1, b1, b2, b3`, `a2, b1, b2, b3`, `a3, b1, b2, b3`. You need these two levels of deduction (`multiply_all`, `multiply_one`) because you need to descend down two levels of "variadicness", see my first comment on the question.

Answer (score 11):

Fold expressions to the rescue again

```
template<typename... Ts>
typelist<typelist<Ts>...> layered(typelist<Ts...>);

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto operator+(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>)
    -> typelist<Ts..., Us...>;

template<typename T, typename... Us>
auto operator*(typelist<T>, typelist<Us...>)
    -> typelist<decltype(T{} + Us{})...>;

template<typename... Ts, typename TL>
auto operator^(typelist<Ts...>, TL tl)
    -> decltype(((typelist<Ts>{} * tl) + ...));

template<typename... TLs>
using product_t = decltype((layered(TLs{}) ^ ...));
```

And you're done. This has the additional benefit over recursion of having O(1) instantiation depth.

```
struct A0;
struct A1;
struct B0;
struct B1;
struct C0;
struct C1;
struct C2;

using t1 = typelist<A0, A1>;
using t2 = typelist<B0, B1>;
using t3 = typelist<C0, C1, C2>; 

using p1 = product_t<t1, t2>;
using p2 = product_t<t1, t2, t3>;

using expect1 = typelist<typelist<A0, B0>,
                         typelist<A0, B1>,
                         typelist<A1, B0>,
                         typelist<A1, B1>>;

using expect2 = typelist<typelist<A0, B0, C0>,
                         typelist<A0, B0, C1>,
                         typelist<A0, B0, C2>,
                         typelist<A0, B1, C0>,
                         typelist<A0, B1, C1>,
                         typelist<A0, B1, C2>,
                         typelist<A1, B0, C0>,
                         typelist<A1, B0, C1>,
                         typelist<A1, B0, C2>,
                         typelist<A1, B1, C0>,
                         typelist<A1, B1, C1>,
                         typelist<A1, B1, C2>>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<p1, expect1>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<p2, expect2>);
```

Comment: This intrigues me. Is there a way to represent it as TL1 * TL2 * TL3 =  crossporduct result?

Comment: basically instead of `using result = product_t<t1,t2,t3>` ...some way to represent it as `using result = decltype(t1{} * t2{} * t3{});`. Hmm, well now that it think about it, since `decltype` is inevitable, simply using the alias as you gave is more intuitive.

Comment: Interesting! Using operator overloading gives you fold expressions instead of the recursions I had to do. Also makes it much more concise. I'll keep it in mind for next time!

Comment: @PasserBy Does all those helper operators and functions need to be in same namespace? I am getting issues with putting everything inside a namespace and accessing product_t using an alias from outside namespace.

Comment: @PasserBy https://wandbox.org/permlink/TcIXTwkI3pWgaFM6 this shows the issue if I put the helper operations inside a namespace

Comment: They have to be in the same one with `typelist`. Read [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).