# Cartesian product of list of templates and list of types to instantiate them with

Tags: c++, c++20, template-meta-programming

Not sure if title is descriptive, but what I would like is this:

input:

1. list of templates(in my case containers) taking 1 (required, can be more optional) type arguments
2. list of types

output:

"cartesian product" where each template in first set is instantiated with every type in second set.

example:

```
template_list<std::vector, std::set> x type_list<int, double> => 
type_list<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>, std::set<int>, std::set<double>>
```

I found this question, but that is about a case when elements of both sets are types.

[How to create the Cartesian product of a type list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122028/how-to-create-the-cartesian-product-of-a-type-list)

I presume that what I want is impossible without macros, but it may be possible that I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in my answer on he linked question, with [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_productf_l), this is a short one-liner (as always):

```cpp
using templates = mp_list<mp_quote<std::vector>, mp_quote<std::set>>;
using types = mp_list<int, double>;

using result = mp_product<
    mp_invoke_q,
    templates, types>;

static_assert(std::same_as<
    result,
    mp_list<std::vector<int>,
            std::vector<double>,
            std::set<int>,
            std::set<double>
            >>);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a_KEhb).

Note that you need `templates` as `mp_list<mp_quote<C1>, mp_quote<C2>>` instead of `template_list<C1, C2>`, since metaprogramming is lot easier if everything is a type. But that's not a huge burden.

Comment: I knew about _q stuff in mp11, but did know it can be used to pack std::vector, this is amazing.

Comment: I started looking at MP11 after seeing this answer and ... it's brilliant. Thanks for bringing it up (again as it turns out)! It's ninja! +1

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)s. Especially [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) is nice for this.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template <template <class...> class... C>
struct template_list {};

template <template <class...> class C, class... Ts>
auto toc(const std::tuple<Ts...>&) {
    return std::tuple<C<Ts>...>{};
}

template <template <class...> class... C, class... Ts>
auto operator*(template_list<C...>, const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup) {
    return std::tuple_cat(toc<C>(tup)...);
}

int main() {
    template_list<std::vector, std::set> templ;
    std::tuple<int, double, float> typel;

    auto res = templ * typel;

    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<decltype(res),
                       std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>,
                                  std::vector<float>, std::set<int>,
                                  std::set<double>, std::set<float>>>);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b8jTW1sjv)

---

A similar solution made into a more classical type trait in which `res` will result in having the same type as above could look like this:

```cpp
template <template <class...> class... C>
struct template_list {};

template <class Temps, class Types>
struct cartesian_product {
    
    template <template <class...> class C, class... Ts>
    static std::tuple<C<Ts>...> toc(const std::tuple<Ts...>&);
    
    template <template <class...> class... C, class... Ts>
    static auto build(template_list<C...>, const std::tuple<Ts...>& tup)
        -> decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<decltype(toc<C>(tup))>()...));

    using type = decltype(build(std::declval<Temps>(), std::declval<Types>()));
};

template<class Temps, class Types>
using cartesian_product_t = typename cartesian_product<Temps,Types>::type;
```

```cpp
int main() {
    using templt = template_list<std::vector, std::set>;
    using typelt = std::tuple<int, double, float>;

    cartesian_product_t<templt, typelt> res;
}
```

Comment: after many years of writing templates I still can not read 3 liners when it comes to variadic template template arguments :) But amazing answer.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Thanks! And I agree. Everytime I start with something like this I never think I'll manage to get it done. Now my brain hurts :-)