# Catch2: Test all permutations of two lists of types

Tags: c++, catch2

I need to write some unit tests in Catch2 where each test case should be executed for each possible permutation of two lists of types. I'd love something like

```
// Some types defined in my project
class A;
class B;

PERMUTATION_TEST_CASE ("Foo", (A, B), (float, double))
{
   TestTypeX x;
   TestTypeY y;
}
```

Where the test case would be executed 4 times with

```
TestTypeX = A, TestTypeY = float
TestTypeX = A, TestTypeY = double
TestTypeX = B, TestTypeY = float
TestTypeX = B, TestTypeY = double
```

Alternatively, something like this would also be possible

```
constexpr A a;
constexpr B b;

TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE ("Foo", float, double)
{
   auto x = GENERATE (a, b); // does not work because a and b have different types
   TestType y; 
}
```

To my knowledge, there is no such thing in catch2. There is , in [type-parametrised-test-cases](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/test-cases-and-sections.md#type-parametrised-test-cases), `TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE` which solves the problem for a single list of types but not each permutation of two lists and there is `TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_TEST_CASE` which solves the problem in case of the first type being a template which is then instantiated with each type of the second list – which is also not what I need here.

Is there any suitable catch2 mechanism for that which I'm overlooking at the moment? I'm using Catch2 version 3.1.0.

My real-world requirements are much larger sets of combinations than this 2x2 example, so manually specifying all permutations would not be my favourite choice.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/list_for_each.html might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the [Cartesian product of type list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122028/how-to-create-the-cartesian-product-of-a-type-list), and then:

```
using MyTypes = cross_product<type_list<A, B>, type_list<float, double>>::type;
// using MyTypes = type_list<std::pair<A, float>, std::pair<A, double>,
//                           std::pair<B, float>, std::pair<B, double>>;
TEMPLATE_LIST_TEST_CASE("some_name", "[xxx]", MyTypes)
{
    using TestTypeX = typename TestType::first_type;  // A or B
    using TestTypeY = typename TestType::second_type; // float or double
    // ...
}
```

In the same way, `TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_TEST_CASE` might be (ab)used with wrapper type:

```
template <typename T>
struct A_with
{
    using first_type = A;
    using second_type = T;
};
template <typename T>
struct B_with
{
    using first_type = B;
    using second_type = T;
};

TEMPLATE_PRODUCT_TEST_CASE("some name", "[xxx]", (A_with, B_with), (float, double))
{
    using TestTypeX = typename TestType::first_type;  // A or B
    using TestTypeY = typename TestType::second_type; // float or double
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I ended up with an adoption of the second pattern, which turned out to be quite suitable